# next.js 13 weird type casting? res.json() number to string

Tags: typescript, next.js, fetch, prisma

i have weird problem that whatever i do, the result of the fetch, is HALFLY casted to the string. (id,price stays as number,  bialko/kcal casted to String but they are BOTH declared as `Float` in prisma). After changing type from decimal to double precision, `api endpoint is returning the objects exactly as i wish. But fetch is doing something which i certainly dont understand. What is important to know, I'm fetching in the server component!

**What i tried**:
-Recreating whole database, altering columns, changing datatypes from numeric to double precision
-npx prisma generate, prisma migrate, deleting migrations

backend code:

```
export async function GET(request: Request) {
    const zestawyWo = await prisma.rankings.findMany({
        where: {},
        select: {
            id: true,
            price: true,
            bialko: true,
            kcal: true,
        },
    })

    if (zestawyWo.length == 0) {
        return NextResponse.json(
            {error: "zestawyWo not found"},
            {
                status: 404,
            }
        )
    }

    console.log(typeof zestawyWo[0].bialko)
    console.log(typeof zestawyWo[0].price)
    console.log(zestawyWo)

    return NextResponse.json(zestawyWo, {
        status: 200,
    })
}
```

component code:

```
async function fetchAllZestawy(orderby?: string): Promise<Zestaw[]> {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/zestawywo`)
    const data: Zestaw[] = await res.json()
    console.log(typeof data[0].bialko)    // string
    console.log(data)   //  result pasted below
    return data
}
```

EDIT: tried fetching data in CLIENT COMPONENT and everything worked as it should (returned kcal and bialko as an number). Seems like there is some kind of weird stuff going on with next.js FETCH.

```
useEffect(() => {
        ;(async () => {
            const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/zestawywo")
            const result = await res.json()
            console.log("CLIENT", result)
        })()
```

CONSOLE.log OF DATA THAT SHOULD BE FETCHED

```
  {
    id: 8,
    price: 31.9,
    bialko: 58.2,
    kcal: 1581,
  }
```

CONSOLE.log OF FETCHED DATA

```
  {
    id: 8,
    price: 31.9,
    bialko: "58.2",
    kcal: "1581",
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insane to say, but managed to resolve the problem by changing `localhost`, to `127.0.0.1` in the fetch url.

```
const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/zestawywo')
```

Next.js surely does have some problems with its fetch because i resolved that accidentaly by resolving another bug, for which the same approach worked:
`TypeError: fetch failed in server componant`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You should not create and export a function for each method. You should try the following:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  // your db logic
  res.status(200).json(zestawyWo);
}
```

If you want to provide a different callback for each method, you could do this:

```
export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  switch (req.method) {
      case "GET": GET(),
      case "POST": POST(),
      // ...others methods
  }
}
```

More information: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

Comment: Forgot to mention that i'm using the new 'app/' directory (next.js 13), and have all the api routes in 'app/api'.  I'm pretty sure i implemented API good.  EDIT: just tried fetching in client component and everythign worked great